# Storing data returned from a yield statement in Python

Tags: python, yield

```
import copy


class BubbleSort():

    def __init__(self, datalist):
        self._datalist = datalist

    def __ascending_sort_algo(self):
        _asc_list = copy.deepcopy(self._datalist)
        _length_of_list = len(_asc_list)
        _has_swapped = True
        _number_of_iterations = 0

        while _has_swapped:
            _has_swapped = False

            for i in range(_length_of_list - _number_of_iterations - 1):
                if _asc_list[i] > _asc_list[i + 1]:
                    _asc_list[i], _asc_list[i + 1] = _asc_list[i + 1], _asc_list[i]
                    _has_swapped = True

            _number_of_iterations += 1
            yield _asc_list

    def __ascending_sort(self):
        _yi_li = []
        iterations = 0
        for _yielded_list in BubbleSort.__ascending_sort_algo(self):
            print(*_yielded_list)
            _yi_li.append(_yielded_list)

        return _yi_li

    def sort(self):
        _asc_sorted = BubbleSort.__ascending_sort(self)
        return _asc_sorted


listi = [4, 7, 5, 3, 2, 7, 9, 3, 1]

A = BubbleSort(listi).sort()
print(A)
```

The output is

```
4 5 3 2 7 7 3 1 9
4 3 2 5 7 3 1 7 9
3 2 4 5 3 1 7 7 9
2 3 4 3 1 5 7 7 9
2 3 3 1 4 5 7 7 9
2 3 1 3 4 5 7 7 9
2 1 3 3 4 5 7 7 9
1 2 3 3 4 5 7 7 9
1 2 3 3 4 5 7 7 9
[[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7, 9], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7, 9], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7, 9], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7, 9], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7, 9], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7, 9], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7, 9], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7, 9], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7, 9]]
```

__ascending_sort_algo is a generator called by the function __ascending_sort

Why do I get a sorted list in every iteration when I append to the _yi_li list?
(please don't mind the naming conventions) and yeah it has to be *this complicated* as it's part of a much bigger codebase

Comment: Because there is one unique `_asc_list`? You print its different state, and yield multiple times, then store multiple (the unique one) in a list, so when printing at the end you see ell same, all same as the same state. If you want to store the different states `yield list(_asc_list)`

Comment: why on earth are you doing `BubbleSort.__ascending_sort_algo(self)` instead of `self.__ascending_sort_algo()`? In any case, **you are yielding the same list object every time**. So of course, you end up with a list with 9 references to the same list

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for the self.__ascending_sort_algo() bit. I'm still quite unsure why when printing I get all the different states but when I append it they're all the same.

Comment: ... becaue when you *print* the list is different. Then you modify the list. But it's always the same list. **that's the issue**. So imagine, `grid = []; mylist = []; grid.append(mylist); print(mylist); mylist.append(0);print(mylist); grid.append(mylist); print(grid)`

Comment: @azro thanks! that worked!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks! I got it now